# Filter values in data frame based on range of unique values from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

I have two large data frames `(nrow = 20,000)`, with common variables in each `(X, Y and Z)`. Each data frame shares some unique values of one variable `(Y)`, but the values of `X and Z` differ. What I would like to do is filter one data frame (the larger of the two `(df2)`), by the range of values of `X` in the smaller data frame `(df1)` for each unique value of `Y`. So, for example, if the range of `X` values in `df1` for a unique `Y` value of 1 is 0.02 - 0.08, then I would like to obtain all values of `X` and `Z` from `df2` where the value of X falls within that range for the given value of `Y`. I would like to make a new data frame containing these filtered values.

Here is some sample code and data to use an example

```
# GENERATE SOME DATA
 set.seed(5)
    df1 <- data.frame(X = round(runif(20, 0.2, 0.3),4), Y = rep(c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8), each = 4), Z = round(runif(20),3))
    df2 <- data.frame(X = round(runif(50, 0.1, 0.6),4), Y = rep(seq(1,10,1), each = 5), Z = round(runif(50),3))  

## ESTABLISH THE RANGE OF X VALUES FOR EACH UNIQUE Y VALUE IN THE DATA FRAME OF INTEREST (df1)

library(dplyr)

df3 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(Y) %>%
  mutate(minX=min(X), maxX=max(X)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(Y, minX, maxX)

## FILTER df2 BY THE RANGE OF Y VALUES IN df1

df4<- df2 %>%  filter(Y %in% df1$Y)
```

So now I have `df2` filtered to give me only the range of `Y` values which are common to both data frames `(df4)`. What I need to do here is to create a new data frame from `df4` which contains only the values of `X` which are within the range of `X` values in `df1` for each value of `Y` `(df3)`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please check your examples.  It is giviing some rrors

Comment: Thanks. There was a missing bracket from the first line of code. Should be correct now

Comment: Also, please consider `set.seed` for reproducibilty

Comment: This has a fundamental flaw: equality of floating-point works a lot but fails without alerting you. For instance, see `sqrt(3^3) == 3` (false). This is due to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) and IEEE-754 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal.